# Connection error - connection refused

Tags: android, android-emulator, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing an Android app, using Mobile ADF in JDeveloper 11.

I used weblogic server with SOAP service. When I test the webservice, its working fine, but I am getting this error after deployment on Android emulator -

```
"cannot connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 7101: java.net.ConnectionException:connection refused".
```

Answer (score 2):

**use**    `10.0.2.2` **instead of** `127.0.0.1`

and for `SOAP`

**use port** `8080` **instead of** `7701`

Comment: Thank you. Could you please how to change IP address to 10.0.2.2 in jdeveloper. I am new to this. I tried changing IP address in "connections.xml" file, but didn't work fine. Please help me.

Comment: @user2586147 try this link http://www.locaproxy.com/technical-configuration/how-to-configure-proxy-in-programming-ide-for-jdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1

> 10.0.2.2  Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

[Reference: Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

Answer (score 0):

Use this address: `10.0.2.2` or the real IP address if you have one.

See also the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)