# ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException] - Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am getting an error while starting my app.
I tried to get data from my WS but I get this instead:

[image]

Here are the logs when I clicked the button to get data:

```
D/Proxy Selector(31153): >>> Java_com_oracle_net_ProxySelectorImpl_getProxyForURL0

D/Proxy Selector(31153): >>> Call getProxyForURL

D/Proxy Selector(31153): >>> initDalvikPointers: 0x60d7ee31 0x60d7ee49 0x60d84030 0x60d8402c

D/Proxy Selector(31153): >>> attachCurrentThreadToDalvik: Attach returned JNIEnv=0x0x69167984

I/System.out(31153): DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found

D/Proxy Selector(31153): >>> detachCurrentThreadFromDalvik: Detach current thread from dalvik VM

D/Proxy Selector(31153): proxy not found!

D/JVM     (31153): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - RestTransportLayer - readResponse] Exception lors de la lecture de la rÃ©ponse : java.io.IOException

D/JVM     (31153): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.contract.adf.application.GenericInvokeRequestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.contract.adf.application.EmbeddedGenericInvokeRequestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.contract.adf.application.GenericInvokeRequestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.contract.adf.application.GenericInvokeRequestHandler.process(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.FeatureContext.handle(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.framework.AdfChannel.handle(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at com.oracle.vm.channel.impl.VMChannelImpl.run(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153): Caused by: ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfInvocationRuntimeException] - Connection refused (Connection refused)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.rest.RestWebServiceOperation.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.JavaBeanOperation.lambda$execute$4(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.util.MonitorUtil.monitorFunction(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.JavaBeanOperation.execute(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.WebServiceDataControlAdapter.invokeOperation(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.bindings.dbf.AmxMethodActionBinding.lambda$execute$10(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.util.MonitorUtil.monitorFunction(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153): 

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.bindings.dbf.AmxMethodActionBinding.execute(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.bindings.dbf.AmxMethodActionBinding.execute(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstProperty.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstEval.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at de.odysseus.el.TreeMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.maf.api.amx.taghandler.UITagHandler._invokeListenerMethod(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.maf.api.amx.taghandler.UITagHandler.handleAmxEvent(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.maf.impl.amx.Dispatch.processAmxEvent(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  ... 12 more

D/JVM     (31153): Caused by: ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException] - Connection refused (Connection refused)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.rest.RestTransportLayer.sendReceiveBytes(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.rest.RestWebServiceOperation.invokeHttpRequestRaw(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  ... 31 more

D/JVM     (31153): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.microedition.io.HttpConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.rest.RestTransportLayer.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  at oracle.adfmf.dc.ws.rest.RestTransportLayer.readResponse(Unknown Source)

D/JVM     (31153):  ... 33 more

D/JVM     (31153): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - GenericInvokeRequestHandler - invoke] InvocationTargetException Erreur : oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfInvocationRuntimeException

D/JVM     (31153): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - GenericInvokeRequestHandler - process] Exception AdfException de processus dÃ©tectÃ©e : oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfInvocationRuntimeException

I/System.out(31153): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - ADFMobileShell - invokeJavaMethod] Exception : ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfInvocationRuntimeException] - Connection refused (Connection refused)

I/System.out(31153): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - adf.mf.internal - logError] Une erreur est survenue au cours de la demande.
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be comments not answer but I don't have 50rep yet.

I am assuming that you are running WS on pc, and app is on real android device in the same local network/wifi.
Try first to access resource(ex. /rest/employees) in web browser on device. If connection is refused as well, check firewall on your pc if is not blocking access.

Comment: i have disabled the firewall , same problem and i can't access to the resource from my mobile browser(Connection refused)

Comment: But you can access resource from your pc don't you? Are you using REST or SOAP? Look at answers in following questions: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6876306/6939481) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811172/connection-error-connection-refused)

Comment: i can access resource from my pc , im using REST